Does a positive response to antidepressants confirm the patient was in fact depressed?
Or, here is another way of phrasing this question… What might happen if you gave antidepressants to a neurotypical patient? Would the patient experience mania or giddiness, or would they simply not experience a change in mood at all?
Depression, like other mood disorders, is diagnosed based on symptoms experienced by the patient.  There is no test or brain scan (to my knowledge) that can conclusively diagnose or rule out depression.  And so naturally, mistakes can happen and someone who is not depressed, but simply going through a difficult period, could end up misdiagnosed with depression.  (Or, someone who does actually have depression might be brushed off as “just going through a rough time” when they try to seek help).
SSRIs and other antidepressant medications are commonly used as a first-line treatment for depression.  If a patient reacts well to SSRIs, can that fact be used to reasonably “confirm” that what they had was actually depression?
